# Difference between AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup and AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am a little hazy about the need for both. I am using both in ECS CloudFormation. It appears that `AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup` is for scaling EC2 instances whereas `AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget` is for scaling containers/tasks. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2):

That is pretty much correct.

- [AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-group.html) is used for creating an Auto Scaling group of EC2 instances
- [AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-applicationautoscaling-scalabletarget.html) is used to specify an application resource that can scale - that is any of a range of resources including ECS service, EMR cluster or DynamoDB. A list of all the resources that can be scaled can be found in the [`ResourceId` parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/application/APIReference/API_RegisterScalableTarget.html#API_RegisterScalableTarget_RequestParameters) description for RegisterScalableTarget.